# Close GAE channel from server side Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, channel-api

In the client side is possible close the socket with connection.close(), but its possible close it from the server side?

Answer (score 0):

Since the socket exists on the client you would have to send a close command from the server to the client

Comment: the problem is that sometimes the client disconnects and the server is not notified (the post call to  /_ah/channel/disconnected/ never happend)

Comment: That does happen, there is a timeout you can set on the client as well as sending a "heartbeat" from the server to see if the connection is live